# How to filter model objects based upon User groups & permissions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset, django-orm

### Background:

I would like to know how to filter model queryset results based upon a models User foreignkey  && its associated names, groups, & permissions.  Here is a simple example of what I would like to happen:

- Lets say there are company cars available for every employee to use (Read only state)
- Lets also say that any employee can choose to use their own car also (Modifiable only by owner)

Listed below is the scenario described above with my initial stab at a solution:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q

user1 = User.objects.create_user("Billy", 'bbob@gmail.com', 'pw');
user2 = User.objects.create_user("Johnny Boy", 'jbo@gmail.com', 'pw2');
user1.groups.add('employee')
user2.groups.add('employee')

class Car(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     carOwner = models.OneToOneField('User')

qObj = Q(carOwner__user_username = user1.username) 

for empGroup in user1.groups:
    qObj |= Q(carOwner__groups__icontains = empGroup)

transOpts= Car.objects.filter(qObj) #All Transportation Options for given user
```

### Question:

I have provided my initial attempt at a solution, but would like to know what a 'correct' way would be to handle such a situation.  Without further ado, here is the question:

Q: How can I filter models based upon a combination of the User's name, groups, & permissions?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want all cars that are either owned by the user or owned by a user of the same group. With you models you could probably do this (not tested):

```
Car.objects.filter(Q(carOwner=user) | Q(carOwner__groups__in=user.groups))
```

Side notes:

This approach probably generates a better query, instead of using string comparison for the email and group name, it will use the user and the user's groups ids.

Use `car_owner` instead of `carOwner`, attributes names in python are [preferably named all lower case and separated by underscore](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. Instead of
`Q(carOwner__groups__in=user.groups))`
you should use 
`Q(carOwner__groups__name__in=user.groups))`